# Playhaven Doesn't Works in iOS

Tags: ios

I am doing play haven interstitial in my iOS app and am getting following two type of error:

1. Request recieved HTTP response: 403
2. Request recieved HTTP response: 200

and I have checked it dismissed type which is `PHPublisherNoContentTriggeredDismiss`.

Anyone have a idea how to fix it?

Comment: Now it's working.You need to test it on device instead of simulator.

Comment: Hi,I am having same issue. Does anyone fixed it?